# Call to undefined method MDB2_Error::setFetchMode()

Tags: php, mysql, pear, mdb2

I am using PEAR's MDB2 to connect to my MySQL DB's.

I have never had a problem before but this particular host is causing me problems.

At first I thought it was the user credentials but I have tested on the same file with a standard `MySQL` code to connect successfully.

```
 //Error Code
 Fatal error: Call to undefined method MDB2_Error::setFetchMode() in /home/topazmar/public_html/db/db.php on line 15

 //Php Code
 $this->conn=MDB2::connect(array(
        'phptype'  => 'mysql',
        'username' => DATABASE_USR,
        'password' => DATABASE_PWD,
        'hostspec' => DATABASE_HOST,
        'database' => DATABASE_NAME,
    ));
    $this->conn->setFetchMode(MDB2_FETCHMODE_ASSOC); //Line 15
```

**Edit**

I outputting $this->conn with a dump

```
[0] => Array
            (
                [file] => /home/topazmar/public_html/db/MDB2.php
                [line] => 979
                [function] => PEAR_Error
                [class] => PEAR_Error
                [type] => ->
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => MDB2 Error: not found
                        [1] => -4
                        [2] => 1
                        [3] => 1024
                        [4] => unable to find package 'MDB2_Driver_mysql' file 'MDB2/Driver/mysql.php'
                    )

            )
```

I do have `MDB2_Driver_mysql 1.4.1` installed along with PEAR and MDB2... Makes me confused, I don't imagine using modrewrites would change this at all.

Comment: The connection is failed, so you got a `MDB2_Error ` which doesn't have `setFetchMode ` method.

Comment: Run `echo $this->conn->getMessage()` to get the actual error message.

Comment: Nice one, but bummer: `MDB2 Error: not found`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your connection is failing and you get back error object (class `MDB2_Error`) instead of connection object (class extending `MDB2_Driver_Common`).

Use `PEAR::isError($this->conn)` to check if the connection succceeded.

[Edit - Hutber]

**This Means You Haven't connected to the db, pw problems, user not privaliaged etc**

Comment: `Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in` Not ideal, I don't fully see why it won't let me do this, but there u go

Comment: Maybe there's now another way to check in PEAR error was returned, I haven't touched PEAR in long time.

Comment: I'm thinking maybe I should avoid it :)

Comment: You can use `$this->conn instanceof PEAR_Error` instead.

Comment: I think got the error, almost less helpful :) but yours `
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'PEAR' (T_STRING) in /home/topazmar/public_html/db/db.php on line 19` See updated question

Comment: Back here again.... On my own question... New machine, but I'm still getting the error and the answer doesn't help me sadly. Any ideas @Marek

Answer (score 1):

In case someone sees this thread and they did install MDB2 and the db drivers correctly: I had the same issue and it turned out I had set insufficient permissions for the db user. Durrr

Answer (score 0):

So for me what fixed it was as simple as installing the MDB2 library from pear.

Assuming you already have PEAR installed:

```
pear install MDB2 
pear install MDB2#mysql
```

From a terminal/cmd window, then I was good to go.

Comment: You should not change your questions but ask a new one. Your new problem and answer are unrelated to the original.

Comment: But I don't think the question changed...I think your answer doesn't explain how to fix it, ekk sorry.

Comment: It did change: first problem was you were getting `MDB2_Error` object. This also means `MDB2` was installed. After moving to new server you got another problem: `MDB2` was not installed.

Comment: +1 :) Ok, I was getting the exact  same error `Call to undefined method MDB2_Error::setFetchMode()` And I don't see the answer helping me, but  either way, if anybody searches this problem they'll have both answers to help them now :)

Comment: Can't plus one myself! Needed it again

Comment: lol still back here in 2022!!